# Evaluating S depending upon following condition: Calculate the sum $S=\Sigma \Sigma \Sigma x_{i} x_{j} x_{k},$

Tags: sequences-and-series, measure-theory, summation, solution-verification, problem-solving

### Suppose that $x_{1}, x_{2}, \ldots, x_{n}(n>2)$ are real numbers such that $x_{i}=x_{n-i+1}$ for $1 \leq i \leq n .$ Consider the sum $S=\Sigma \Sigma \Sigma x_{i} x_{j} x_{k},$ where summations are taken over all i, $j, k: 1 \leq i, j, k \leq n$ and $i, j, k$ are all distinct. Then S equals

---

$S=\sum \Sigma x_{i} x_{j}\left(L-x_{i}-x_{j}\right) i \neq j$

where $L=x_{1}+x_{2}+\ldots+x_{n}$

$=L \sum \Sigma x_{i} x_{j}-\sum \Sigma x_{i}^{2} x_{j}-\sum \Sigma x_{i} x_{j}^{2}$

$=\mathrm{L} \sum \mathrm{x}_{\mathrm{i}}\left(\mathrm{L}-\mathrm{x}_{\mathrm{i}}\right)-\Sigma \mathrm{x}_{\mathrm{i}}^{2}\left(\mathrm{L}-\mathrm{x}_{\mathrm{i}}\right)-\Sigma \mathrm{x}_{\mathrm{i}}\left(\mathrm{M}-\mathrm{x}_{\mathrm{i}}^{2}\right)$

where $\mathrm{M}=\mathrm{x}_{1}^{2}+\mathrm{x}_{2}^{2}+\ldots .+\mathrm{x}_{\mathrm{n}}^{2}$

$=\mathrm{L}^{3}-3 \mathrm{LM}+2 \Sigma \mathrm{x}_{\mathrm{i}}^{3}$

**What to do next?**

Comment: The condition $x_i=x_{n-i+1}$ is redundant as it can be obtained through replacing each $m\in\{i,j,k\}$ by $n-m+1$.

Comment: So it will lead to S=S...check my edit part

Comment: I have no idea what the question is. Your $S$ is just the third elementary symmetric polynomial in $n$ variables up to a scale factor, here evaluated on a symmetric sequence, though none of your manipulations seem to use this. Your identity for $S$ in terms of power sum symmetric polynomials is just a special case of Newton's identity.